# Why does wrapping output in quote create extra quote after?

Tags: powershell, regexp-replace

I want to `ls -name` a folder and wrap the result between the quotes`. However the result make an extra quote after.

```
> (ls -name) -replace '(.*)', '"$1"'
"apple"""
"orange"""
"dog"""
"cat"""
```

Why is that?

Comment: Probably because [`.*` doesn't match everything](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) but does match an empty string. What about: `(.+)`?

Comment: You can see at [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/IWidse/1), that it matches a 2nd time at the end of the string. I'm not quite sure why this happens. On a side note, you can remove the capture group and use `$0` in the substitution to represent whole match: `(ls -name) -replace '.+', '"$0"'`

Comment: C# and PowerShell use the same .NET RegEx engine so the linked answer applies to PowerShell as well.

Comment: That is odd.  Alternatively `ls -name | % { "\`"$_\`"" }`

Comment: Another one that works: `(ls -name) -replace '^|$', '"'`. This replaces both the beginning (`^`) and the end (`$`) of the input string by a single `"`.